# managing a radius value in sass over multiple sheets

Tags: css, sass

So i have just picked up SASS.. awesome tool, but i cannot find the answer to one question before i start..

What is best practice with SASS for managing a variable value to be referenced in mulitple sheets.

For example, a radius set to 5px..

```
/* coreValues.scss */
$radiusNormal : 5px
```

Is it best to declare all these variables in a single master `.scss` file then import said file in each scss sheet created eg.:

```
/* featureA.scss */
@import 'coreValues';

.boxA{
  -webkit-border-radius: $radiusNormal ;
     -moz-border-radius: $radiusNormal ;
      -ms-border-radius: $radiusNormal ;
          border-radius: $radiusNormal ;
}
```

.

```
/* featureB.scss */
@import 'coreValues';

.footerContainer{
  -webkit-border-radius: $radiusNormal ;
     -moz-border-radius: $radiusNormal ;
      -ms-border-radius: $radiusNormal ;
          border-radius: $radiusNormal ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the best way in order to keep the values all in one place, and then changed for every instance throughout.

You could improve it so coreValues.scss is named _coreValues.scss, which would then not be compiled into a css file by itself, as it is deemed to be a [partial](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials).  The file itself would be linked exactly as you have it here, and wouldn't need the underscore adding to the @import.

Comment: Ahh right ok. Thank you very much, i was wondering what the partials were. Cheers.